# Счётчик пользователей на странице Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите каким образом реализуют счетчики текущих пользователей на странице. Например у меня есть интернет магазин с каталогом и я хочу выводить в карточке товара, что на данный момент его просматривают N количество человек.

Насколько я понимаю реализация через БД будет неверной, но могу ошибаться.

Comment: Отслеживают количество запросов от авторизованных (или нет) пользователей за последние Н секунд/минут/часов.

Comment: Реализация через БД, само собой. Только через Redis, а не MySQL или что-то другое, конечно...